# "Internal Error in key fixup - unable to locate entity" error but database updated as expected

Tags: breeze

I'm struggling to debug this error because, although it's consistently reported, the app's behavior is as intended. Would appreciate pointers as to what it means and how I could go about debugging its source.

Apologies for being vague but, since I'm getting the desired result, I'm unsure what other information to provide.

**UPDATE**

I've created a repro of this issue and attempted to focus the code on the problem. The error is thrown consistently even though the database is updated correctly. There's a single saveChanges in the code and it uses the save functionality from the dataservice.js in the Breeze Todo sample. SaveOptions.allowConcurrentSaves is false.

Entirely at a loss to explain it and have looked through my EF code to see whether I'm making an obvious mistake but can't see it. The bundle sent to the WebAPI SaveChanges method looks correct (correctly populated with IDs etc.) too.

https://github.com/DazWilkin/BreezeJS.ScoreIssue

**UPDATE 6th February**

The issue remains unresolved by Wade's helpful answer. Unfortunately, unless I can understand what it is I'm doing wrong or learn that this is a bug, I'm going to have to abandon the use of Breeze in this project and revert to crappy, plain old AJAX calls.

It would appear that the issue revolves around the server returning a zeroed GUID when saving changes. The method returns no errors. I would be thrilled to learn that this is a bug in my entity model but I'm doubtful.

Here's the failure:

breeze.debug.js: 11954

```
var ix = this._indexMap[tempValue];
if (ix === undefined) {
   throw new Error("Internal Error in key fixup - unable to locate entity");
}
```

When the code reaches this point, the value of this._indexMap is correct and is:

```
{"bcb6e670-00fc-469d-8531-5767f40bf3c1":0}
```

BUT the value of tempValue (as returned from the Web API call by the server) is wrong:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

The realValue is correct and is:

```
1093b975-7686-4621-8336-77c38ed36de0
```

Backing up the stack. Here are the results from the AJAX call, breeze.debug.js: 12574. See that the tempValue is zeroed on return from the server/WebAPI call. The realValue is correct. This is what the database contains. The row is added to the table without problem.

```
"KeyMappings": [
    {
        "$id": "4",
        "$type": "Breeze.WebApi.KeyMapping, Breeze.WebApi",
        "EntityTypeName": "...Score",
        "TempValue": "51877f5b-811f-4260-bd5b-cf9965159597",
        "RealValue": "92b73b8a-8b33-45cd-9822-ca7c0c5d5d9a"
    },
    {
        "$id": "5",
        "$type": "Breeze.WebApi.KeyMapping, Breeze.WebApi",
        "EntityTypeName": "...PropertyValue",
        "TempValue": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "RealValue": "1093b975-7686-4621-8336-77c38ed36de0"
    }

],
```

Verified against what's received serverside in saveBundle. NB the IDs of both entities received at the server have valid GUID IDs.

```
"entities": [
    {
        "ID": "51877f5b-811f-4260-bd5b-cf9965159597",
        ...
        "entityAspect": {
            "entityTypeName": "Score:...",
            "entityState": "Added",
            "originalValuesMap": {},
            "autoGeneratedKey": {
                "propertyName": "ID",
                "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "ID": "bcb6e670-00fc-469d-8531-5767f40bf3c1",
        ...
        "entityAspect": {
            "entityTypeName": "PropertyValue:...",
            "entityState": "Added",
            "originalValuesMap": {},
            "autoGeneratedKey": {
                "propertyName": "ID",
                "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
            }
        }
    }
],
```

Unsurprisingly, the values sent to the server by the AJAX call that are created in breeze.debug.js: 10494 saveBundleStringified are correct and the same as those received by the server (won't reproduce but I assure you they are).

And, from my code, when the saveChanges is called,

```
manager.getChanges().length == 2
manager.getChanges()[0].ID() == "51877f5b-811f-4260-bd5b-cf9965159597" (Score)
manager.getChanges()[1].ID() == "bcb6e670-00fc-469d-8531-5767f40bf3c1" (PropertyValue)
```

and, as expected, these match the (temp) values of the entities' IDs during saveChanges, received by the server...

What am I doing wrong?? If I had hair, I'd be tearing it out!

Answer (score 5):

I've solved it.

My inconsistently applied (!) convention is to make the setters internal/private on code first types. I say inconsistently because, after feeling that I'd exhausted all possibilities, I discovered that the PropertyValue type, i.e. the one originating the error, had an internal set.

Having removed this and rebuilt the solution, the problem is solved!

So:

```
public Guid ID { get; internal set; }
```

Should be:

```
public Guid ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for reposting on this topic.  I'll make sure something gets added to the breeze docs about this issue.

Comment: Thanks Jay! I wish I'd thought to trace through in detail earlier in my frustration ;-) It was tedious but it was worthwhile. Really thrilled that I can continue to use Breeze now for this project.

Comment: I think you may able to still keep your original code if you mark up your class with the correct json.net serialization attributes (Json.NET is what breeze is using on the server to serialize your objects). There should be some docs on the json.net web site about this.

Answer (score 3):

## Update Jan 27:

Based on your comments to Sergey's answer, you may have been trying to do something with the changed entities before the save operation completed.

Those entities remain in their changed state ... often with temporary primary and foreign keys ... until the server reports a successful save.

You probably shouldn't touch them until the save succeeds. As Sergey observes, you should locate your post-save processing in the save success callback.

```
return manager.saveChanges()
              .then(saveSucceeded)
              .fail(saveFailed);
```

**You should not wrap the `saveChanges` call in a jQuery `Deferred`**. That is a waste of time and complexity. The `EntityManager.saveChanges` method returns a promise that your caller can consume. The view models can add their own success and failure callbacks

```
dataservice.saveChanges()
           .then(hooray)
           .fail(sadTrombone);
```

### Concurrent saves

I noticed in your code that you are guarding against illegal concurrent saves using the [time-delay approach](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/concurrent-saves#timedelayedsaves) you found in the **Todo** sample.

That approach is really only suitable for the demo. It won't work at all for you if your view models need to perform some tasks when the save succeeds. It won't work because the dataservice can't return a promise to the view models with the time-delay approach.

If you need non-blocking saves, check out the "[**Save Queuing**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/concurrent-saves#savequeuing)" plugin described in the "[Concurrent Saves](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/concurrent-saves)" topic under the "Cool Breezes" section.

### Creating entities succinctly

While looking at your code, I couldn't help noticing that your entity factory methods in *scoreissue.1.0.ts* were a bit verbose. What you have written as:

```
export function Business(manager, o: IBusiness) {
  var business = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Business").createEntity();
  business.ID(breeze.core.getUuid());
  business.Name(o.name);
  manager.addEntity(business);
  return business;
}
```

could be as simple as:

```
export function Business(manager, o: IBusiness) {
  return manager.createEntity("Business", {
    ID: breeze.core.getUuid(),
    Name: o.name,
  });
}
```

The `EntityManager.createEntity` shortcut is new since you wrote this code so don't feel bad about having missed it.

## Original answer:

[Wrong direction. Preserved to make sense of DazWilkin comment that the problem is on the client.]

Where is this being generated? On the server? If so, you can subclass EFContextProvider and override `SaveChangesCore`. Call the `base.SaveChangesCore` and put a try/catch around it. Inspect the `saveMap` argument. The EFContextProvider is open source; I'd start digging here.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur with multiple simultaneous save requests pending at the same time both involving key generation.  Does this error only occur during a save?  If so try setting your SaveOptions.allowConcurrentSaves to false. If this causes a different error, (a concurrent save error) to occur then your problem definitely has to do with concurrent saves.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a good place to look if you determine that it is a CLIENT-SIDE exception ... which it probably is.

Comment: Thanks! I've hit another error (gads!) but will revert the code and try this out. I have been encountering concurrent save problems but have slapped deferreds around the code in order to synchronize to a single save. Will try your suggestion and report back. Love the framework!

Comment: allowConcurrentSaves is false.

Comment: A false `allowConcurrentSaves` the default. And it's a good default too! Because if you add a new item, save and save again before the first completes ... you'll get 2 identical items in the db. You really have to think about how you want to deal with someone pounding the "Save" button (especially if that "someone" is your app code). Saves usually aren't idempotent.  Take a look also at the dataservice.js in the latest TodoSample. Notice how it implements a concurrent save latch ... and retries the save if one is in progress. This *might* work for you for a while

Comment: I say "a while" because it really isn't a robust approach. If a save fails, the stacked saves will keep coming.  Frankly, I think a good approach would disable saves, while another save is in progress. You have to work out the user experience but it's the best way.

Comment: Dan, I really am pretty sure that this issue has to do with simultaneous pending saves. Can you confirm whether the problem goes away once you insure that you do not have more than one save in flight at any time? If not, I can spend some time on it, but I really need confirmation one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and I've solved it with help of jQuery deferred object. My dataservice save method now looks as follows:

```
saveChanges = function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    if (manager.hasChanges()) {
        manager.saveChanges()
            .then(function () { def.resolve() })
            .fail(function (error) {
                handleSaveError(error);
                def.reject();
            });
    } else {
        logger.info("Nothing to save");
        def.resolve();
    };

    return def.promise();
};
```

And I call it from my view models also using jQuery deferred object:

```
$.when(dataservice.saveChanges())
 .done(function () {
      ...some actions
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understand your saveChanges function but don't understand why it (would) solve(s) the problem.

Comment: In my case this problem occured when saveChanges method wasn't the last in function. Other words, saveChanges method is asynchronous, when I did some operations with save data (for example, destroying it) immediately after saveChanges method, breeze shows key fixup error. To avoid this, I had to wait the end of this method.

Comment: Interesting. This makes sense and mirrors my code (saveChanges is the last function). I will try it and report back. Thanks.

Comment: You have the right idea, Sergey, but you do not need to use jQuery deferred. See my updated answer.